# compiling grpc with a multi-module maven app

Tags: java, maven, grpc, grpc-java

I've my architecture as follows.

**Two Servers**

*moduleA/src/main/resources/fileA.proto*

*moduleB/src/main/resources/fileB*.proto

Client (Browser facing server end point calling above two servers)

*service/src/main*

**Issue/Question:** I've the following POM in my moduleA to begin with but it's not generating stubs.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.22.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proto file location should be `src/main/proto/`.
Also, the version of protobuf doesn't seem like matching. in dependency, protobuf version is 3.6.1 where the protoc plugin is using 3.9.0.

Comment: quick question if you don't mind, what is the right architecture to share a proto file between two separate modules (or microservices or jars), both are to be deployed on different machines, maybe compiling both modules on the same machine or perhaps compiling client on a different machine after server is deployed, what is the industry practice to share the IDL between the two, do I copy the proto file across modules and re-generate java code, just trying to wrap my head around in real life team work scenarios.

Comment: It also seems to me that I might have to depend on the server's jar file, link to it and call methods using the implementation, trying to figure out how client can access classes of the server?

Comment: @AppDeveloper sharing proto files are somewhat tricky, some companies doesn't have this issue, because they are using a mono repo like Google. This questions show up often but afaik not a good solution out there yet.